# How do I open a modal onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I want to open a modal when my input type "Verwijderen" is pressed. But it doesn't show up? What am I doing wrong? Even W3schools examples don't work in Fiddle for example. I am missing something I guess but what?

```
<td colspan="2">
<input type="submit" style="width:140px;" value="Opslaan"/>
<input
    type="submit"
    style="width:140px;"
    id="cancelForm"
    class="ketchUp-default"
    value="Annuleren"/>
<input
    type="submit"
    id="deleteEvent"
    value="Verwijderen"
    style="width:140px;"
    class="ketchUp-default"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="confirm-delete"/>

<div
    class="modal fade"
    id="confirm-delete"
    tabindex="-1"
    role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm Delete</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>You are about to delete one track, this procedure is irreversible.</p>
                <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
                <p class="debug-url"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post a full jsfiddle including your JS?

Comment: what you means with " input type "Verwijderen" is pressed", please add full jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using BootStrap 3? I think your mistake is that you are not using the "#" ID selector in your data-target on your input. Change your input code to this:

```
<input
    type="submit"
    id="deleteEvent"
    value="Verwijderen"
    style="width:140px;"
    class="ketchUp-default"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#confirm-delete"/>
```

Here is a working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PCdlTpfPQMir4ePicUXp?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Your input is a `submit`, so your page is submitting the form, and the modal does not have time to be shown.

Try to convert your `submit` button to a simple `button` (not submit), and your modal will be shown.

```
<input
    type="button"
    id="deleteEvent"
    value="Verwijderen"
    style="width:140px;"
    class="ketchUp-default"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="confirm-delete"/>
```